# Print array to CSV in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, csv

In the model i have the following method, inspired by [RailsCasts #362](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

The model is Post, and a column in Post is named Author. Author is an array of strings. I want to loop out each entry in the Author array into its own line of a CSV file, instead of just printing the array to one line. I am trying to do it as such, in the Post.rb (model class file), 
but im getting the error "undefined local variable or method `randomsched' for #<Class:0xccd0490>"`

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    author.each do |x|
      csv << x
    end
  end
end
```

backtrace

```
Started GET "/posts.csv" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-15 07:19:36 -0400
Processing by PostsController#index as CSV
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `author' for #<Class:0xccd0490>):
  app/models/post.rb:26:in `block in to_csv'
  app/models/post.rb:25:in `to_csv'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Comment: Required full backtrace of error to investigate problem!

Comment: @maxd I think i have posted that now

Comment: What exactly is Post.author? For example, what is the output of `Post.first.author` in console?

Comment: @thebenedict => ["C", "B", "B", "D", "C", "A", "D", "B", "B", "D", "D", "B", "A", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "D", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B"]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one CSV per Post:

```
  class Post
    def to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        author.each do |x|
          csv << [x]
        end
      end
    end
  end


  Post.first.to_csv
```

Note the change from `def self.to_csv` to `def to_csv` making it an instance method instead of a class method. Also `[x]` instead of `x` as `csv <<` expects an array.